# AHK keywait for multiple keys (missing (SC) (VK))?

Tags: script, autohotkey

I got this function from here :

https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/1arcp8q/comment/kr1km61/?context=3

It waits for one or multiple keys to be pressed, But It doesn't accept scan code (SC) or Virtual keycodes (VK).

I'd like this function to work also with scan code (SC) or Virtual keycodes (VK) like this :

```
if keys_wait_multi("abc{SC28}{VK10}{F12}") {
    MsgBox("you pressed one of the keys")
}

Keys_Wait_Multi(keys, options := "") {
    key_pressed := false
    ih := InputHook(options)
    ih.KeyOpt("{All}", "VE")
    ih.KeyOpt(keys, "-E")
    ih.KeyOpt(keys, "NS")
    ih.MinSendLevel := 1
    ih.OnKeyDown := (ih, *) => ih.Stop()
    ih.Start()      ; start input hook
    ih.Wait()       ; wait for input hook to end
    if_success := (ih.EndReason = "Stopped" ? true : false)
    return if_success
}
```

Any help to do so please?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

if keys_wait_multi("abc{SC10B}{VKB2}{F12}") {
    MsgBox("you pressed one of the keys")
}

Keys_Wait_Multi(keys, options := "") {
    key_pressed := false
    ih := InputHook(options)
    ih.KeyOpt("{All}", "V")
    ih.KeyOpt(keys, "-E")
    ih.KeyOpt(keys, "NS")
    ih.MinSendLevel := 1
    ih.OnKeyDown := (ih, *) => ih.Stop()
    ih.Start()      ; start input hook
    ih.Wait()       ; wait for input hook to end
    if_success := (ih.EndReason = "Stopped" ? true : false)
    return if_success
}
```

`SC10B` is a special key and `VKB2` is the media_stop key on my keyboard. Replace them with your own key codes.

Comment: It works with SC and VK, But there is something strange :
if a key has a symbol rather than an alphabet letter e.g ":" Its SC is {SC34}
when I put {SC34} as a parametre to wait for it to be pressed, then press F12 to call the function, while waiting when I press the key ":" It sends the symbol ":" then show the MsgBox. the same thing happens with scan codes of  keys have these symbols ",;:<"

Comment: But if a key is not any of these ",;:<" e.g "a" when I put "a" as a parametre to wait for it to be pressed, then press F12 to call the function, while waiting when I press "a" It doesn't send "a" from the first time, But It shows the MsgBox first without sending "a", when I close the MsgBox then press "a" from the second time, It sends "a".

I want the same thing that happened to "a" to happen to the scan codes of these keys ",;:<"

I would like to use SC or VK because my keyboard layout input languages are sometimes French and some other time is set to Arabic.